# Определить, содержит ли текст символы, отличные от букв и пробела.

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки, файловая-система, перекодировка

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
String file, FileR,line,result1;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Введите имя файла, из которого считывать строки:");
file = in.nextLine();
Scanner out = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Куда сохранить результат?");
FileR = out.nextLine();
    //запрашиваем кодировку
    Scanner inEncoding = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println("Введите название кодировки входного файла:");
    String encodingStr = inEncoding.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Введите название кодировки выходного файла:");
    String encodingStrout = inEncoding.nextLine();
        //cчитывание из файла
        InputStream inFile = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] str = new byte[inFile.available()];
        inFile.read(str);
        if (encodingStr.compareToIgnoreCase("windows-1251")  == 0) {
        line = new String(str, "windows-1251");               
        } else if (encodingStr.compareToIgnoreCase("Unicode")  == 0) {
         line = new String(str, "UTF-16");
        }  else if (encodingStr.compareToIgnoreCase("UTF-8")  == 0) {
            line = new String(str, "UTF-8");
        } else {
            return;
        }
        //условия задания
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\p{L}]*",Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
        boolean matches=p.matcher(line).matches();
        if(matches)
        {
            result1="Текст не содержит символы, отличные от букв и пробела";
        }
        else{
            result1="Текст содержит символы, отличные от букв и пробела";
        }
            OutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(FileR);
         if (encodingStrout.compareToIgnoreCase("windows-1251")  == 0) {
         byte[] result = result1.getBytes("windows-1251");
        outFile.write(result);              
        } else if (encodingStrout.compareToIgnoreCase("Unicode")  == 0) {
            byte[] result = result1.getBytes("UTF-16");
        outFile.write(result); 
        }  else if (encodingStrout.compareToIgnoreCase("UTF-8")  == 0) {
             byte[] result = result1.getBytes("UTF-8");
        outFile.write(result);
        }}}
```

Comment: Строчки должны читаться из заданного файла. Результат выводить так же в заданный файл (другой). Имена файлов получить из командной строки. Предусмотреть обработку ошибок, а также возможность задавать кодировку считываемого и выводимого текста.

Comment: Выводит результат нормально, сохраняет в введенной кодировке. Но всегда говорит, что есть символы, отличные от букв и пробела,какую кодировку бы не задавала, хотя в файле только буквы.  Не могу понять где ошибка: в перекодировке,считывании или в регулярных выражениях?

Comment: Не задавайте вопросов, состоящих из одного кода. Опишите суть вашего вопроса таким образом, чтобы на него можно было дать ясный и однозначный ответ. Попытайтесь решить задачу самостоятельно, и если возникнут проблемы, задайте вопрос об этих проблемах, а не приводите свое домашнее задание в комментариях.

Comment: Во-первых, я не просто привела свое домашнее задание в комментариях, а дописала все условия, чтобы было понятнее для чего эта заморочка с перекодировкой и почему я просто не ввела текст с консоли, а считывала с файла и выводила в файл. Я попыталась выполнить самостоятельно и во втором комментарии сказала, что проблема в том, что выводит результат нормально, но не правильно определяет, что текст не содержит символов, отличных от букв и пробела. Не могу понять, что этому способствует: неправильное считывание строк из файла, кодировка или неправильная работа регулярных выражений.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Не нужно создавать по новому экземпляру сканера на каждый вопрос. Достаточно одного экземпляра на все вопросы.
2. Используемые ресурсы (потоки, сканер) надо закрывать.
3. Для сравнения введенной строки с одним из возможных вариантов можно использовать не `if`, а `switch` (начиная с Java 7).
4. Обработки ошибок нет даже самой примитивной.
5. В вашем регулярном выражении не предусмотрена возможность пробела. 
   Ваш паттерн проверяет, содержит ли файл одни только буквы; если в файле есть пробелы или переносы строк, паттерн не совпадет.
6. Даже если исправить паттерн, чтобы учесть пробелы, останется еще одна проблема: в файле может быть [BOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2), который тоже не буква. Это также надо учесть.

Так что в первом приближении получается что-то вот такое:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class So_600623_FileEcodings {

  static String fixEncodingName(String encName) {
    switch (encName.toLowerCase()) {
      case "windows-1251":  return "windows-1251"; 
      case "utf-16":        return "UTF-16"; 
      case "utf-8":         return "UTF-8"; 
      default: 
        System.out.println("Недопустимая кодировка: " + encName);
        System.exit(1);
        return null;        // Compiler beleives that one day 
                            // System.exit() may return control :)
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    InputStream inpStream = null; 
    OutputStream outStream = null; 
    Scanner in = null;
    try { 
      in = new Scanner(System.in);
      String inpFileName, outFileName, dataStr, resultStr;

      System.out.println("Введите имя файла, из которого считывать строки:");
      inpFileName = in.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Куда сохранить результат?");
      outFileName = in.nextLine();

      //запрашиваем кодировку
      System.out.println("Введите название кодировки входного файла:");
      String inpEncName = fixEncodingName(in.nextLine());
      System.out.println("Введите название кодировки выходного файла:");
      String outEncName = fixEncodingName(in.nextLine());

      //cчитывание из файла
      inpStream = new FileInputStream(inpFileName);
      byte[] bytes = new byte[inpStream.available()];
      inpStream.read(bytes);
      dataStr = new String( bytes, inpEncName);

      // It may contain BOM. Q&D workaround suitable for UTF-8 and UTF-16
      if ((bytes[0] & 0xEE) == 0xEE) dataStr = dataStr.substring(1);

      //условия задания
   // Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\p{L}]*",Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS); // А пробелы где?
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\p{L}\\s]*",Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS); 
      resultStr = p.matcher(dataStr).matches()? 
        "Текст не содержит символов, отличных от букв и пробела": 
        "Текст содержит символы, отличные от букв и пробела";

      outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
      byte[] result = resultStr.getBytes(outEncName);
      outStream.write(result);              

    } catch (IOException x) { 
      System.out.println("Ошибка ввода-вывода:");
      x.printStackTrace(); 
    }
    finally {
      // Открытые файлы надо закрывать
      if (outStream != null) 
        try { outStream.close(); } 
        catch (Exception x) { 
          System.out.println("Ошибка закрытия выходного файла:") ;
          x.printStackTrace();
        }
      if (inpStream != null) try { inpStream.close(); } catch (Exception x) {}  
      if (in != null) try { in.close(); } catch (Exception x) {}     // Сканер тоже
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, есть пару вопросов, но вы итак очень помогли, поэтому покопаюсь в литературе, отдельное спасибо за ссылку на BOM, буду теперь учитывать:)